# SQL share calculation

Tags: sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

I have a database with the following schema:

```
fund(fundID, fundName,totalShares) 
price(fundID,priceDate,price) 
trans(sin,fundID,transDate,shares) 
customer(sin,name,address,phone)
rep(repid,repName) 
customerRep(sin,repId)
```

My task is to find the unique customers that hold shares to a certain fund ("Energy") after transactions each day. I'm not exactly sure what a trans represents i.e. shares purchased or bought. I'm looking for hints not answers, use sample code if you can, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT c.sin, c.name
FROM customer c 
INNER JOIN trans t ON t.sin = c.sin 
WHERE t.funcID = XXXX 
AND t.transDate = '2012-10-19'
```

If you want text matching i.e. "Energy"

```
SELECT c.sin, c.name
FROM customer c 
INNER JOIN trans t ON t.sin = c.sin 
INNER JOIN fund f ON f.fundID = t.fundID
WHERE f.fundName = 'Energy' 
AND t.transDate = '2012-10-19'
```

EDIT:

From your replies, the transaction table (trans) can contain numerous records for the same date for the same fundID that would be buy/sells for that fund.

In that case you will need to SUM those. A subquery could do that. I believe the below could give you the unique number of sin, fundID, transDate and remaining_shares. This way you trim all the transactions and keep only the ones that are positive and then you can join that with your customers.

```
SELECT t.sin, t.fundID, t.transDate, SUM(t.shares) AS remaining_shares 
FROM trans t 
WHERE SUM(shares) > 0 
GROUP BY t.sin, t.fundID
```

HTH

Comment: Yes the code you provided is where im stuck at, I have been doing the same thing however I need to only pull out the customers that "have" shares. For instance, the shares of "Energy" on a given day "2012-10-10" may have a series of transactions. At the end of the day, only one customer may actually own shares of that stock. The problem is I dont understand what the table trans is actually telling me.

Comment: Yepp, that code answered it. I didnt realize that transactions could be negative. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions can be many things. Puchases, sales, corporate events, accrued income, take ons, take offs.

It would seem though that you need to look in table `trans` to start with.

I dont think this is the correct site to learn about what transactions (unless you are talking database) are, but the programming side can be helped

Comment: Right, however im not trying to learn about transactions, this is midterm question. Im asked to determine only the customers that actually own shares at the end of each day. In order to do this, the trans table must somehow indicate whether a transaction is selling/buying shares. This is why Im confused about the trans table.

Comment: A transaction on a given day might not indicate that the customer owns any shares in the fund. Take for instance a buy of 100 units on day 1. The customer will be in the owners list. A sell of 50 units on day 2 will still leave the customer in the owners list, but a sell of 50 on day 3 should remove the customer from the owners list.